# Convert Date to Continuous Scale/Variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there anyway to convert or instruct ggplot to interpret a column of Dates as a continuous variable?

My data (`df`) looks like the following:

```
Location       Date     Value
56.28,-36.57 2011-01-10  32
56.28,-36.57 2010-02-08  40
52.24,-36.58 2010-03-22  18
52.24,-36.58 2011-06-14  39
52.25,-36.59 2012-04-10  41
52.25,-36.59 2010-04-09  38
```

I have tried to plot the data with the following command:

```
g=ggplot(df) + geom_boxplot(aes(factor(Location),Value, col=Date))+ geom_jitter(aes(factor(Location),Value),size=1) + scale_colour_gradient(low='red',high='green')
```

But received the following error message:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

If I convert the Date to a Date object (e.g. `col=as.Date(Date)`), I receive the following error:

```
Error in unit(tic_pos.c, "mm") : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0
```

The goal is to have the Date column dictate the color of the points, with earliest dates having color red and later dates having the color green on the color gradient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to wrap the date column in `as.numeric`.  However, as @Hadley pointed out in the comments, the `trans` argument in `scale_colour_gradient` can take a value of `date`.  This has the added benefit (relative to what I had previously posted) of the legend displaying date values, not numeric.

Here it is altogether:
*Notice also that I moved the `col` argument to `geom_jitter` (not `geom_boxplot`)*

```
ggplot(df) + geom_boxplot(aes(factor(Location),Value))           +
    geom_jitter(aes(factor(Location),Value, col=Date),size=2)    +  # <~~~ col
    scale_colour_gradient(trans="date", low="red", high="green") +
    xlab("Location")
```

[image]

---

*previous response, using `as.numeric` kept for comparisons*

You can wrap the column in `as.numeric`.  Also, I moved the `col` argument to `geom_jitter` (not `geom_boxplot`).

```
ggplot(df) + geom_boxplot(aes(factor(Location),Value))+
    geom_jitter(aes(factor(Location),Value, col=as.numeric(Date)),size=2) +
    scale_colour_gradient(low='red',high='green') + 
    theme(legend.position="none") + xlab("Location")
```

[image]

Comment: Rather than doing `as.numeric(Date)`, you can do `scale_colour_gradient(trans = "date")`

Comment: @hadley +1 for scale_colour_gradient(trans = "date"). Very useful!

Answer (score 1):

You can try taking the min and max of the Date column and them mapping dates to a scale on the range 0 to 1.

```
df$Date=as.POSIXct(df$Date)
min=min(df$Date)
max=max(df$Date)
as.numeric(difftime(df$Date,min,units='days'))/as.numeric(difftime(max,min,units='days'))

[1] 0.42426474 0.00000000 0.05298048 0.61992950 1.00000000 0.07570895
```

Add that to your data frame and you should be in business.